# How to replace duplicated index-calculating formula

Tags: c++

In my code, I often use a formula that returns me an index into a 2D array:

```
cells[cellToMarkX + cellToMarkY * xSize] 
// ...
if (cells[j + i * xSize] == 0)
//...
else if (cells[j + i * xSize] >= 5)
//..
cells[cellToMarkX + cellToMarkY * xSize] += 4;
```

I'm not sure if I should instead create some function like

```
getCell(int x, int y)
```

or should is this unnecessary and I should prefer to use a macro?

Comment: if you use the formula very often, the function is not unnecessary

Comment: DRY is a fine principle. but at some point you take it too far. `x = x + 2;`. "Ooops, now I've repeated 'x' twice and violated DRY. Now I need `add_two(x)` to prevent the repeated xs... and now I have repeated `d` in add, blah blah blah.

Comment: yes but if I used #define  to define this simple forula of cell[x+y*xsize]  would it not be more proper?

Comment: imho what you "should do" or what is "more proper" is completely opinion based

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/manual.md#multi_view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularly in the example you give, you might want to consider precomputing as well, as in:

```
int myindex = j + i * xSize;
if (cells[myindex] == 0)
....
else if (cells[myindex] >= 5)
```

but to answer your question more directly, a function call is not out of place here, particularly if you declare it with the `inline` attribute. In many cases, a good optimizing compiler will generate the same code regardless of whether you use a macro or a function, but that is of course implementation-dependent.

Personally, I'd prefer a function.

Comment: something like: inline getCell(int x, int y){ return cell[x+y*xsize]; } ?

Comment: precomputing will not work because I use this formula in many functions in my program

Comment: Yes. `inline int getCell(int x, int y) { return cell[x+y*xsize]; }`

Comment: ok, but how to make it assignable? If I have got: cells = new short[xSize * ySize];

Comment: @Mateusz You could declare a structure with your xSize and Size as members, and getCell as a function that refers to those members. Just a thought.